# Exchange 2010 SP1 won't allow messages to be deleted in OWA

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

Before upgrading to Service Pack 1 of Exchange 2010, OWA worked fine. We were able to do everything with no issues. After the upgrade, we can no longer delete messages within OWA unless we open up the message and delete it using the delete button inside of the message window. The error we get is this:

[image]

We've searched online and only found [several](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/exchange2010hosters/thread/e45d7277-b205-4791-a430-631b163a5072) [posts](http://forums.msexchange.org/OWA_Problem_after_Updating_to_SP1/m_1800538473/tm.htm) [pointing](http://forums.msexchange.org/m_1800538801/mpage_1/key_/tm.htm) us to rename or delete the web.config file in the inetpub directory.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: is there anything in your event logs? IIS usually puts something in there (granted, it's normally pretty cryptic, but a clue nonetheless).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be one of the many IIS config issues that arose from the Exchange 2010 SP1 upgrade. Just as a sanity check, I would urge you to look at the web.config file in the OWA IIS directory. Make a backup of the file before making any changes.

Open the file in an editor and look for a string resembling this:

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpRedirect enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

If that's present in that particular file, you should remove those lines and restart IIS. See if that works first. It was the core problem in my recent SP1 upgrade.

Comment: I tried it and it seems that it still doesn't work on some machines. We performed this on both of our Exchange servers and restarted IIS. Not sure why it's a hit and miss thing.